# Python how to know script was executed directly with name or using python interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, scripting, arguments, command

How to differentiate between `./my_script.py` and `python3 ./my_script.py` from inside the script? I checked `sys.argv`, but both have exact same values (`['./my_script.py']`)!

I wanted to differentiate between these two because, later I'm using `sys.args` to re-launch the same command in a remote machine. This will throw error when script is called as `python3 my_script.py` as `sys.args` contains just `['my_script.py']`, which is not a valid executable.

Snippet:

```
def launch_remote():
    argv = ' '.join([shlex.quote(arg) for arg in sys.argv])
    command = 'cd "{}"; nohup {} >>"{}" 2>&1 </dev/null'.format(os.getcwd(), argv, OUT_PATH)
```

```
Local invocation: ./my_script.py
sys.argv: ['./my_script.py']
Matches expectation: YES
Launch remote succeeds: YES

Local invocation: python3 ./my_script.py
sys.argv: ['./my_script.py']
Matches expectation: NO
Launch remote succeeds: YES

Local invocation: python3 my_script.py
sys.argv: ['my_script.py']
Matches expectation: NO
Launch remote succeeds: NO
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail about what you want to do with this script? Perhaps an example of the script you already have.

Comment: @blueteeth I updated the question to give more clarity. Please check.

Comment: But why does it matter how it's invoked? You can get all the other args by doing `sys.argv[1:]`, and then use them on the remote however you want. Surely the remote isn't going to have `my_script.py` on it, so why does it matter how it is used?

Comment: @blueteeth Remote has `my_script.py`. That entire folder is synced.

Comment: My comment still stands